# Generate interrupts for purpose of stress testing

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt

I'm testing the quality of a generated PWM signal on a Raspbery Pi. I would like to test how it behaves if there are lots of interrupts coming.

Is there a way to fake interrupts or force 2000 keyboard interrupts per second via a script?

Answer (score 1):

How fast can you type? ;-)

Both USB and network are easy ways to generate interrupts:

- if you have a USB audio or video device, recording might to the trick
- use `ping -f` or a TCP or UDP flood tool, e.g. ([tcpflood](http://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-tcpflood/)

If you have the equipment and a suitable kernel, a square-wave generator hooked up to one of the [GPIO ports](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals) should work too.

You might also be able to do something with [hrtimers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214197/hrtimer-repeating-task-in-the-linux-kernel), but I'm really not sure what the level of support on ARM and RPi for this is.